# How will Ripple affect Bitcoin exchanges?

Tags: ripple

Will every Bitcoin exchange be under pressure to also operate as a Ripple gateway in order to gain access to the additional liquidity that Ripple creates for markets?

Answer (score 3):

As Ripple appears to allow one to create exchange listing for any pair of currencies, it might very well server as an exchange unto itself. It is possible that the project will replace the traditional exchanges, possibly turning them into Gateways to put money in and out of the system instead.

Then again, that might be far in the future - at the present time there is a healthy amount of scepticism surrounding how safe the Ripple system is, so not a lot of people would be willing to abstract their money even further with it than they are used to.

Comment: Do you happen to have a source (URL) for that scepticism about the safety?

Comment: @Joshua It's an overall feeling I get when talking to people about Ripple. If you are part of the BF, here is a topic where people express some of their concerns - https://bitcoinfoundation.org/forum/index.php?/topic/84-ripple/ - people are still looking into the code, pondering the safety of consensus approach to ledger creation, discussing the way ripples are distributed, problems after the initial launch and so forth.